# Bayes Rule combining two sensors

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network

> You are programming a demining robot. As the robot drives along, the
> prior probability of a mine being in its immediate vicinity is 0.001
> The robot is equipped with a mine detecting sensor which sounds a bell if it detects a mine nearby. If there is a mine nearby, then the probability of the sensor ringing
> the bell is 0.95. If there is no mine nearby, the probability of the sensor ringing the bell is 0.01

> You now fit a new sensor to the robot. This uses a different
> method to detect mines from that used by the first sensor, and if it does
> detect a mine, it sounds a buzzer. If there is a mine nearby, then the
> probability of the new sensor sounding the buzzer is 0.90, and if there
> is no mine nearby, the probability of the sensor ringing the bell is 0.02.
> How would you use the ringing alarms from both sensors to compute
> the probability of there being a mine nearby?

With b = bell, m = mine, z = buzzer I have:

P(b,z|m)p(m) / P(b,z)

My only thought is that b and z are independent which would give:

P(b|m)P(z|m)P(m) / P(b)P(z)

P(b) = P(b|m)P(m) + P(b|¬m)P(¬m)

and likewise for z. I plug in values and get > 1, I'm not sure how to approach it

Answer (score 1):

> If there is a mine nearby, then the probability of the new sensor
> sounding the buzzer is 0.90, and if there is no mine nearby, the probability
> of the sensor ringing the bell is 0.02.

I am assuming that there is a typo above, and that on the new sensor, there is
a probability of $0.02$ of the buzzer sounding, if there is no mine nearby.

I am also assuming that false positives or false negatives with respect to the bell are totally independent of false positives or false negatives with respect to the buzzer.  That is, I am assuming (for example) that there is no *atmospheric condition* that would simultaneously cause both sensors to malfunction.

As I see it, the assumption in the above paragraph is justified, because otherwise, I don't see how the problem can be attacked.

---

I am unsure about the informality of the following approach, but the approach
makes sense to me.

Let $E_1$ denote the event that there is a mine in the vicinity.
Let $E_2$ denote the event that the bell rings. 
Let $E_3$ denote the event that the buzzer sounds.

There are $8$ possibilities, re either event $E_k$ occurs or it doesn't 
for $k \in \{1,2,3\}$.

What you do is assign a probability to each of the $8$ possibilities occurring. 
Then, you consider the $4$ **known alternatives** re either event $E_2$ occurs
or it doesn't and either event $E_3$ occurs or it doesn't.

Based on your computation of the $8$ probabilities of how the events may unfold,
you use Bayes Theorem to assign a probability to event $E_1$ occurring, based on
each of the $4$ alternatives with respect to events $E_2$ and $E_3$.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1: the bell rings and the buzzer sounds.}}$

Probability of mine is $0.001$. 
If there is a mine, probability of bell is $0.95$. 
If there is a mine, probability of buzzer is 0.90.

Therefore, probability of mine and bell and buzzer is 
$P_1 = 0.001 \times 0.95 \times 0.90.$

Probability of no mine is $0.999$. 
If there is no mine, probability of bell is $0.01.$ 
If there is no mine, probability of buzzer is $0.02.$

Therefore, probability of no mine, and bell and buzzer is 
$P_2 = 0.999 \times 0.01 \times 0.02.$

Therefore, in Case 1, which is focusing exclusively on the situation where both
the bell and buzzer sound, the chance of a mine is

$$\frac{P_1}{P_1 + P_2}.\tag 1$$

---

The other $3$ alternatives, re the bell and the buzzer are analyzed in the same
way as that done in Case 1.  You end up with a computation formatted the same
way as that of (1) above.